# multiple handshakes on socket.io connect

Tags: node.js, socket.io, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am writing the server for a mobile application and have chosen to use socket.io for push notifications from the server to the app but I am having trouble setting up socket.io

There is currently an endless stream of handshakes being initiated upon io.connect(server:port)

```
debug - client authorized
info  - handshake authorized HXtC1UPzcsEzO8X7x2B1
debug - client authorized
info  - handshake authorized aE7hMGDpp5InO1UWx2B2
debug - client authorized
info  - handshake authorized GBx_3n-8Lvbuo4QJx2B3
debug - client authorized
info  - handshake authorized tOEl0F5wNlh4xkn1x2B4
debug - client authorized
info  - handshake authorized K55Oit22yN9JDWxhx2B5
debug - client authorized
...
```

I am using socket.io-titanium for the client-side of the application and I cannot tell which end is causing this connection issue.

Client:

```
var io = require('socket.io-titanium');
var socket = io.connect('http://myserver.com:3000');
socket.on('connect', function (data){
  Ti.API.log("socket.io connected");
});
socket.on('update', function (data){
  Ti.API.log(data);
});
```

Server:

```
index = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/index.html');
var updates = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(index);
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(updates);

var clients = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("Server Connection Event");
    socket.on('i am client', console.log);
});

io.set("polling duration", 10);
io.set("close timeout", 30);
updates.listen(3000, function(){
 console.log("Updates listening on port 3000");
 console.log("");
});
```

I received "Server Connection Event" once in the middle of a VERY long stream (100+)

I believe the idea of the handshake is that the connection only needs to be authorized & established once per user until the connection is closed.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Are you testing this on your local laptop or over the internet?

If it's over the internet, there is a possibility that your socket.io client is falling back to older poll based protocols. This can happen if, for example, your ISP happens to run a HTTP/1.0 proxy. Such a proxy will reject the Connection Upgrade which is defined in HTTP/1.1 and thus Web Sockets will fail and your client will fall back to older methods such as long-polling, etc.

If you are encountering this when running on your local laptop it could be some other issue. Can you open up Chrome and then open Developer Tools > Network and then select the Web Sockets filter. Now navigate to your site and see if your Web Socket is established correctly.

Comment: I am testing on the internet and my ISP is Comcast. My server is hosted on AWS. I will look into the proxy unless you happen to know if Comcast uses this type of proxy

Comment: That would be hard to answer since there will be multiple routers and proxies and gateways on your route. So my suggestion would be to try the Developer Tools method I mentioned and see if your websocket is connecting at all. If you see something like /socket.io/1/websocket and status says pending, then websockets work. If you see an error, then web sockets is not working.

Comment: Also since you mention AWS, is your app behind ELB by any chance? If so that is the problem. ELB does not allow long lived HTTP sessions. They have a hard timeout. This means that ELB will drop your websocket session once its alive for 30 secs by default. There is no work around for this. We host on AWS as well. However due to this reason we use Route 53 with Weighted Round Robin balancing and point our websockets to use the DNS there instead of the ELB. ELB will not work with WebSockets.

Comment: Also, if your server is using Node.js Cluster this will happen. You then need to use something like Redis so all your instances share the socket.io informations.

Comment: My app is not currently behind ELB but that is only because we are still working on it. The plan was to put it behind ELB when it was complete and ready for testing then for production as well. Is Route 53 w/ Weighted Round Robin the best alternative? I had also considered using a COMET connection (http long polling) but with your explanation, it seems that will also be effected by the hard timeout. I know that Facebook uses COMET for their notification system, but it seemed that Web Sockets was more fitting for our app. Any suggestions?